# Mysql - sorting domains and ignoring any www. in an efficient way

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table of domains that I want to sort "alphabetically", but I don't want all of the www.domain ones at the end.

Right now (with a basic ORDER BY Domain), it sorts like this, for example:

```
amazon.com
google.com
reddit.com
stackoverflow.com
www.etsy.com
www.facebook.com
www.pintrest.com
www.yahoo.com
zebras.com
```

I would like it to sort like this:

```
amazon.com
www.etsy.com
www.facebook.com
google.com
www.pintrest.com
reddit.com
stackoverflow.com
www.yahoo.com
zebras.com
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? As you can imagine, it could be a pretty big table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

select * from T order by REPLACE(Domain, 'www.', '');

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient query, in terms of just the query, would be to add a column to the table, and store the value you want to order by in that column, and add an index with that as the leading column.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE mydomain ADD seq_domain VARCHAR(80) COMMENT 'value used order rows';
UPDATE mydomain SET seq_domain = IF(domain LIKE 'www.%',SUBSTR(domain,5),domain);
CREATE INDEX mydomain_IX2 ON mydomain (seq_domain, domain);
```

Doing all that work isn't entirely efficient... but it makes for a very efficient query, e.g.

```
SELECT t.domain
  FROM mydomain t
 ORDER BY t.seq_domain
```

---

Otherwise, you'll need to be ordering on an expression that has to be evaluated for every row, and MySQL will have to perform a "Using filesort" operation to get the rows in a particular order.

```
ORDER BY IF(domain LIKE 'www.%',SUBSTR(domain,5),domain)
```